# How do I change ownership/permissions of a mounted virtualbox shared folder in Debian?

Tags: mysql, permissions, virtualbox, mount

I'm trying to mount a shared folder and use it as the mysql datadir.

Having succesfully mounted and setup my datadir config, mysqld fails because it lacks the appropriate permissions

I have it mounted to /var/lib/mysql and earlier attempts with /srv/sql ran into the same issue:

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 root    root     272 Feb 27 12:22 mysql
```

Trying to run `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` makes no difference, as does creating a subfolder and trying to use that.

Here's the mysql entries in syslog:

```
Feb 27 12:22:23 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Feb 27 12:22:23 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: 130227 12:22:23 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
Feb 27 12:22:23 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: 130227 12:22:23 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Feb 27 12:22:23 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: #007/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
Feb 27 12:22:23 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: 130227 12:22:23 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: 130227 12:22:24  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: 130227 12:22:24  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: 130227 12:22:24  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: InnoDB: the directory.
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld: InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
Feb 27 12:22:24 tomjn-debian-dev-vm mysqld_safe: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Feb 27 12:22:39 tomjn-debian-dev-vm /etc/init.d/mysql[5085]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Feb 27 12:22:39 tomjn-debian-dev-vm /etc/init.d/mysql[5085]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Feb 27 12:22:39 tomjn-debian-dev-vm /etc/init.d/mysql[5085]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Feb 27 12:22:39 tomjn-debian-dev-vm /etc/init.d/mysql[5085]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Feb 27 12:22:39 tomjn-debian-dev-vm /etc/init.d/mysql[5085]:
```

The VM itself has debian 6 with apache/php/mysql installed with minimal changes ( I changed my.cnf to use a different datadir then changed it back ). Host machine is OS X Mountain Lion and Virtualbox 4.2.6 with the additions/extensions installed and the USB addon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to mount the shared folder manually using the mysql user id:

Here is an example:

```
$ id mysql
uid=105(mysql) gid=112(mysql) groups=112(mysql)
```

then you would do:

```
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf share_name -o rw,dmode=777,gid=112,uid=105 /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, this mounted the folder, and it appears to have given it the right permissions according to `ls -al`, will the command to mount be the same or will I need to figure out the gid every time? mysqld starts from the looks of it but talks about upgrade of tables necessary, but I think that's a different issue

Comment: Yes, i think that is a different issue. The uid and gid are constant on the system. Also "dmode=777" from the mount command, gives read-write permissions to everyone. You can try to automate the mount by editing /etc/fstab, so you don't need to run the command every time you boot the VM.